# make get request on user clicks. (non javascript)

Tags: html, get, click, image

I have and link like this (plain html)

```
<div> 
<a href="http://Link location/userpage.html">My link</a>
<p>When a user clicks on this "my Link" I need to make a get call to fetch a small    image from server for tracking purposes</p>
</div>
```

The user must be directed to his link location but the fetching of the image from server must be done in background.

I can add something static like this

```
<img src ="image location for tracker">
```

but how can i associate it with user clicks.

Comment: Normally AJAX would be use to do that. But you do not want any javascript or you do not have any Javascript?

Comment: This is especially for users who don't have any javascript enabled on their browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of JavaScript I think what you have mentioned would be quite difficult to achieve (but happy to be proved wrong). My question back would be does you hosting allow for any type of simple server side scripting?

If yes, you could make the links point to a simple php or classic asp page which can do the image call or execute the tracking code then redirect the user to the original destination.